# bootstrap timepicker using id in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I had time picker of 24 hrs format in my form. I used the picker twice in my form, but the thing is the first field time picker was working. unfortunately the second is not working. If i use the second field as first, its working. Can you help me for this problem….

```
javascript:
function mytime()
{
$('#timepicker2').timepicker({
            minuteStep: 1,                 
            maxHours: 24,
            showMeridian: false              
        });
}

first field:
<div class="form-group">                                    
   <label for="OrdTime" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Order Time</label>  
        <div class="col-sm-9">                                   
              <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">                                    
                <input class="form-control" onclick="mytime()" name="OrdTime" id="timepicker2" value="<?php if($FmData['OrdTime']){echo $FmData['OrdTime'];}?>" type="text">
              </div>
        </div>
</div>

second field:

    <div class="form-group">    
        <label for="DelTime" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Delivery Time</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">     
             <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">  
                 <input class="form-control" onmouseover="mytime()" name="DelTime" id="timepicker2" placeholder="HH:MM" value="<?php if($FmData['DelTime']){echo $FmData['DelTime'];}?>" type="text" style="width: 100%;">
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: need example your code

Comment: The two pickers have same attribute "name"?

Comment: use class name instead of ids

Comment: Edit your question and paste in your code there, we can't read it in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use class in java-script instead of ids, because id name should be only one in the form.

Java-script:

```
function mytime()
{
$(".timepicker2").timepicker({
        minuteStep: 1,                 
        maxHours: 24,
        showMeridian: false              
    });
}
```

first field:

```
<div class="form-group">                                    
    <label for="OrdTime" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Order Time</label>  
        <div class="col-sm-9">                                   
            <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">                                    
                <input class="form-control" onclick="mytime()" name="OrdTime" id="OrdTime" value="<?php if($FmData['OrdTime']){echo $FmData['OrdTime'];}?>" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

second field:

```
<div class="form-group">    
    <label for="DelTime" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Delivery Time</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">     
         <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">  
             <input class="form-control" onmouseover="mytime()" name="DelTime" id="DelTime" placeholder="HH:MM" value="<?php if($FmData['DelTime']){echo $FmData['DelTime'];}?>" type="text" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have two input picker with same class, and you should initilize the timepicker with the class:

```
function mytime()
{
    $('.timepicker').timepicker({
        minuteStep: 1,                 
        maxHours: 24,
        showMeridian: false              
    });
}

<div class="form-group">                                    
   <label for="OrdTime" class="col-sm-3 control-label">New Time</label>  
        <div class="col-sm-9">                                   
              <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">                                    
                <input class="timepicker form-control" onclick="mytime()" name="OrdTime" id="timepicker1" value="<?php if($FmData['OrdTime']){echo $FmData['OrdTime'];}?>" type="text">
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">                                   
              <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">                                    
                <input class="timepicker form-control" onclick="mytime()" name="OrdTime" id="timepicker2" value="<?php if($FmData['OrdTime']){echo $FmData['OrdTime'];}?>" type="text">
              </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but I used for datepicker its working and why not for time picker?

Comment: If i use this means, the time picker is filled to both fields but I need to  fill for each field separately

Comment: So, you need have two input with two differents "id" (id="timepicker1", id="timepicker2"), and you should initilaize each input separately with the id ($('#timepicker1').timepicker({...}); , $('#timepicker2').timepicker({...});)

Comment: why should i use the same script twice?

Comment: To fill for each field separately

Comment: i too had this idea. but i should not use that twice